# What is the difference between susy-breakpoint and susy-media?

Tags: css, sass, susy-sass

The only difference seems to be that you can pass a new grid as `susy-breakpoint`'s second argument. Why not just always use `susy-breakpoint` and leave off the second argument?

Simply put: In which scenario(s) would you opt to use `susy-media` over `susy-breakpoint`?

Related Docs:
http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `susy-media` is our built-in media-query handling.
- `susy-breakpoint` was built to integrate with the popular Breakpoint plugin, before `susy-media` existed.

If you have Breakpoint installed, then `susy-breakpoint` will call on their more complex and powerful media-query syntax. If you are not using Breakpoint, then `susy-breakpoint` calls `susy-media`, and you are really just using an alias.

Comment: so ideally using `susy-breakpoint` is the right way to go, so you can swap the math behind the scenes without having to refactor too much code, I guess?

Comment: That's how it's designed, yes. If you don't ever expect to use Breakpoint, then it probably doesn't matter.